# Is it possible to back-up Windows 10 context menus that currently display or have been modified?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu

Is it possible to export or do a backup of Windows (10) right-click context menus across Windows Explorer? E.g., menus when right-clicking a file, folder, empty space in a folder, etc.

I'll be doing a full Win10 -> Win10 reformat and am dreading losing all of my context menu layouts and customizations I've done, beyond just the mere insertion of entries by program installers themselves. I realize context menu items are just registry entries in HKCR, but I'd rather not have to blanket-export/import the entire key, but also not have to manually pore through the entire key, finding and picking out all the entries that currently display or that I've modified/inserted (and compounded by the various scenarios of "All", "folder", varying file extensions, empty space, etc).

So if there's a way to find or target only context menu entries that currently display, or have been inserted/modified manually and not by a program installer, or have modified dates that differ from creation dates (which I don't believe the registry keeps track of dates) -- it would be a huge help. I understand this may not be possible, however.

Comment: Have not used myself but this software has got a registry backup feature so give it a try :https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thewindowsclub.com/right-click-context-menu-extender-for-windows-7-released/amp

Answer (score 0):

You could try Nirsoft Shell View and export its items (select all for export). This could like result in conflicts, so I do not really recommend it.

Better, I think, than format and reinstall would be to use the Microsoft Media Creation link to do a Repair Install. You could try Keep Everything and see if this resolves your issues. OR, you could keep just Data and then reinstall your programs. This will keep your Profile and Data. Reinstalling programs goes quickly and context menus rebuild quickly.

Microsoft MCL:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10  .  Use the second button and run in place.

Only do a full format if your Windows User Profile is not working. Even then, reinstalling programs will rebuild context menus.  If you know what customizations you have, use the Nirsoft tool above to save them and then restore them.

Go very carefully. Damaged contexts are very hard to fix.